# printing "Hello" instead of "Hello, world!"

Tags: assembly

I am just learning assembly.  When I use an on line assembler, it prints "Hello, world!" as expected.  However when I use nasm which I just installed I only get hello.  Why does this happen?

```
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov edx, len    ;message length
    mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

    section .data

    msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;our dear string
    len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that on my machine (x86-64 Linux).

Comment: How are you assembling this code?

Comment: I am using nasm filename, my machine is also x86-64 linux(vm) and am running with ./a.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explain in the comments, you are assembling the code like this:

```
nasm helloWorld.asm
```

The problem with this is that

1. You are not assembling it like for an executable file
2. You are not linking it after you have assembled if for an executable file

Under Linux, you would be assembling this code to an ELF file. To do that, run these commands:

```
nasm -f elf helloWorld.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o helloWorld helloWorld.o
```

The first command assembles the code into an object (`.o`) file to be built into an ELF file. The second command takes that object file and turns it into an ELF (executable) file.

To run it, type this:

```
./helloWorld
```

Comment: ok, the last program that I wrote must have been to print hello, This works.